# How to tell which application or model will be processing a given URL?

Tags: python, django

So for example: if I'm working in an arbitrary application and or model but I want to get a handle to the application and / or model that will be actually handling the current URL in the browser address bar.

UPDATE: my question was perhaps not clear enough. I need the reference to the application inside a model, not a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.request.resolver_match.namespace

Answer (score 0):

A request isn't handled directly by an app or a model. You can use the [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) function to get the view that will handle a URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. views can handle url. You can write a view and in urls.py file you can set written view for a specific url

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

But if you want handle all urls by just one view, you should specify your url pattern in a way, that covering all url.